# Referencing ANSI escape sequences in environment variables within awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm sharing a source file defining different ANSI escape codes for different colors. The codes are sourced in a shellscript (bash) which also starts an awk script and the envvars are referenced in awk.

However I'm not getting the output I want - i.e., the colors.

Examples in bash:

```
export Red='\033[0;31m'
export Color_Off='\033[0m'

  # This works, Output is "Hello" in Red
echo $Red Hello $Color_Off
```

Examples in awk (the envvars are still exported/set):

```
  # This does not
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "Output: " ENVIRON["Red"] "Hello" ENVIRON["Color_Off"] }'
Output: \033[0;31mHello\033[0m

  # This works, Output is "Hello" in Red
awk 'BEGIN { R="\033[0;31m" ; O="\033[0m" ; print R "Hello" O }'
```

I'm assuming the answer is lying there right in front of me, but I fail to find it just now.

Comment: Pipe the output from those two commands to `xxd` and I expect you'll see the difference. Then think about what awk sees when you write `R="\033"` as opposed to `ENVIRON["Red"]`.

Comment: in `od -c` I see what I'm also suspecting - that the environment variable is interpreted as a string - "\033" - while set in awk it is interpreted as an escape character. I must be sleep deprived, because I don't see how to solve it _with_ the environment variable.

Comment: Use `-v red="$Red"` to assign the value to a variable outside of awk so the shell evaluates the escape sequence. I'm not sure how you would do that inside awk directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this, but you need to declare color escape sequences slightly differently. Use ANSI C quoting to directly insert escape sequences instead of using a escape-led string and letting the shell expand later:

```
export Red=$'\e[0;31m'
export Color_Off=$'\e[0m'
awk 'BEGIN { print "Output: " ENVIRON["Red"] "Hello" ENVIRON["Color_Off"] " Bye" }'
```

This should work as expected. I also believe this is the superior way to declare colors (for instance, it's done this way in [Zsh's `colors` contrib function](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Misc/colors)).

Comment: Great answer! According to my posted question, which is tagged with [bash], this works. When I tested the sollution with ksh on AIX (PPC7) it doesn't. I'll have to address this for my live situation (make others use bash for scripting), but your answer matched my question. Thanks.

Comment: @sastorsl You're welcome. I have little experience with Korn shell so I'm not sure about their quoting rules or if an `\e` equivalent is even available.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following awk command instead (slightly modified from yours):

```
$ awk -v R=$Red -v O=$Color_Off 'BEGIN { print R "Hello" O }'
```

Comment: Thank you. Still, I wanted to use the environment variables inside awk so I don't have to maintain a long chain of input to awk.